# Prevent Stretching of image in Scrollview in iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, imageview, autoresizingmask

I am adding a few buttons to the scrollview. I am setting a background of the button with an image. When you see the output, the image seems to get stretched. I would like to avoid this.

So I have tried this:

Created a custom view, which handles the image and made this image fixed away from the edges.

Did this for the autoresizing part:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < imageCount; counter++) {

        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_img0%d.jpg",mRoutePointId,counter+1];
        UIImage *infoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

        GalleryImage *galleryItem = [[GalleryImage alloc] initWithImage:infoImage];

        UIButton *infoImageButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, 0, infoImagesScrollView.frame.size.width, infoImagesScrollView.frame.size.height)];
        infoImageButton.tag = counter;
        [infoImageButton setImage:galleryItem.galleryImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [infoImageButton setImage:galleryItem.galleryImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [infoImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoImageButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [infoImageButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_img0%d.jpg",mRoutePointId,counter+1] forState:UIControlStateApplication];
        [infoImagesScrollView addSubview:infoImageButton];
        xOffset+=infoImagesScrollView.frame.size.width;
    }
```

CustomView.m

```
#import "GalleryImage.h"

@implementation GalleryImage

@synthesize galleryImage;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage*) image
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
//        galleryImageView = nil;
        galleryImage = image;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [galleryImageView setImage:galleryImage];
}
```

Need some guidance on how to ensure that the image does not stretch when added to the button.

Welcome to other suggestions as well..

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a question of the image view's `contentMode`.

Comment: e.g. try `galleryImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter`

Comment: i have both landscape and portrait images. The landscape images are working fine. Don't get stretched. but portrait images tend to get stretched.

Comment: placed galleryImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter in awakeFromNib.. but still not change...